# regex in python using OR for single or double quotation marks

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write regex in python for either single or double quotation marks from these examples:

animal="cat"

animal="horse"

animal='dog'

animal='cow'

It comes up empty when trying with |

```
re.compile("animal=\"|'(.+?)\"|'").findall
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You need to either group "choice of single or double quotes" in parentheses `(\"|')` or use a character class `[\"']`. I see what you're going for, but the way your current regex actually reads is _match `animal=\"` OR match `'(.+?)\"` OR match `'`_

Comment: Do you care if the open quote is different than the closing quote?

Comment: This works for me
    re.compile("animal=[\"'](.+?)[\"']").findall
Thank you, iamnotmaynard

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of back-reference:

```
r = re.compile(r"""animal=(["'])(.+?)\1""")
```

This guarantees that the opening and closing characters are the same.

It's time to test it:

```
assert r.search('animal="cat"').group(2) == "cat"
assert r.search('animal="horse"').group(2) == "horse"
assert r.search("animal='dog'").group(2) == "dog"
assert r.search("animal='cow'").group(2) == "cow"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logical `OR` doesn't works on `'` and `"` instead use a character class :

```
>>> s="""animal="cat"
... 
... animal="horse"
... 
... animal='dog'
... 
... animal='cow'"""
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r"""animal=["'](.+?)["']""",s)
['cat', 'horse', 'dog', 'cow']
>>>
```